# Using Kestrel without ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I want to use Kestrel HTTP Server to do HTTP things unrelated to the ASP.NET abstraction. I don't want to install any of the ASP.NET packages just Kestrel and use Request/Response model to write a fast/performant HTTP application.

In the old days this was done with `HttpListener`, but since everything now runs on Linux I can't use HTTP.sys.

Every Kestrel example shows how to use it with ASP.NET Core using the `WebHost` thingy.

I just want to run a console application that opens a port and gives me HTTP requests.

I'm almost 100% sure that this is possible. How I'm I supposed to do it?

Comment: I believe Kestrel is written in .net core, so you'd be hard pressed to not use those packages.

Comment: Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserver?view=aspnetcore-2.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.internal.hostingapplication.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_Internal_HostingApplication__ctor_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_RequestDelegate_Microsoft_Extensions_Logging_ILogger_System_Diagnostics_DiagnosticListener_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IHttpContextFactory_

Comment: Kestrel runs a series of middleware, so you just need to learn how to customize which middleware components to load, and remove all ASP.NET Core related ones, leaving only what matters to you, such as static file middleware and URL rewrite middleware.

Answer (score 4):

Kestrel has many dependencies to Asp.Net packages in both Transport and Http layer. even if you want to use just `Kestrel.Transport` and implement your own HttpServer, you need the packages like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` in `Kestrel.Transport.Abstraction` and `Kestrel.Transport.Socket` libraries. So if you want to remove these dependencies, you need a full customize on all Kestrel class libraries.